# simple js giving syntax error on edge only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

I've written a simple vanilla js plugin that uses file reader API to build a  file uploader component;

https://github.com/Cerealkillerway/fileUploader

it works fine except that it throws a syntax error on ms-edge or ie;
on edge it throws the error on the opening bracket of the updateLabel function:
https://github.com/Cerealkillerway/fileUploader/blob/master/js/fileUploader.js

The error is on this function:

```
    let updateLabel = function(type, value) {
        for (let label of instanceLabels[`${type}Labels`]) {
            let labelSpan = label.querySelector(':scope > span');
            let prevValue;

            switch(value) {
                case '++':
                prevValue = parseInt(labelSpan.innerHTML) + 1;
                labelSpan.innerHTML = prevValue;
                break;

                case '--':
                prevValue = parseInt(labelSpan.innerHTML) - 1;
                labelSpan.innerHTML = prevValue;
                break;

                default:
                labelSpan.innerHTML = value;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, we shouldn't have to go through thousands of lines of code. And post the complete error message.

Comment: The problem is probably that you're using ES6 features like template strings.

Comment: the template strings are fine. You mention IE in your question, but don't go beyond that. you code is definitely not compatible with IE.

Comment: can't reproduce the problem on my side, according to your description and the code in the updateLabel function, I try to create a sample using [for...of statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), it seems that everything works well on Microsoft Edge browser (Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0), but this statement doesn't support IE browser. So, please check your browser version, and whether the issue is related to the updateLabel function. You could try to add debugger in this function to debug it.

Comment: Ok I know I'm using es6, but the file is transformed by babel and the dist version should work everywhere right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having similar issues, the problem was due to `:scope` selector which is not supported in edge nor ie;

I've solved the problem by importing a polyfill for it (https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-qsa-scope)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MS Edge takes the idea of function declaration very seriously. Where other browsers are allowing you to get away with this, the code below is actually invalid (line 790):

```
for (let label in labelsClasses) {
    function findLabel(container, labelsClasses, label) {
      /* implementation */     
    }
}
```

Function declarations can only be declared in the "top-level" of code. That specifically means they can only be created in the global/module scope or at the top level of another function declaration.

Change the declaration to use a function expression:

```
for (let label in labelsClasses) {
    let findLabel = function(container, labelsClasses, label) {
      /* implementation */     
    }
}
```